# Sequelize: getOne() throws 'Unknown column (...) in field list' if where statment is not based on PK and works for PK search

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using `getOne()` function to extract user data with associated models. If I use `PK` in the `where` clause like this: `where: { ID: 128 }` - it **works fine**. Which means that associations and query config are correct.

But if I'm trying to find the user by `email` field like this: `where: { email: 'email_of@user_with_ID_128.com' }` - Sequelize throws an error `Unknown column (...) in field list` for fields of the deepest associated models. The email is correct and it points to the same user as the search by ID. If I exclude the associations from the query config or set `required: false` - the query is successful and user can be found with `email`.

This is the query line:

```
return models.User.findOne(config).then(user => { console.log(user) });
```

And the options/config object:

```
config = {
    where: { ID: 128 }, // THIS WORKS
    // OR
    where: { email: 'email_of@user_with_ID_128.com' }, // THIS THROWS ERROR
    include: [
        {
            nested: true,
            model: models.UserComponent,
            attributes: ['ID', 'isDisplayed', 'displayIndex'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Component,
                    required: true,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: models.ComponentType, // error relates to this model
                            required: true // doesn't throw error if set to false
                        },
                        {
                            model: models.ObjectType, // and error relates to this model
                            required: true // doesn't throw error if set to false
                        },
                        {
                            model: models.ComponentContent,
                            required: false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    nested: true    
};
```

Models definitions:

```
const User = connectionPool.define('user', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    surname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    }
});
const Component = connectionPool.define('component', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    defaultIsDisplayed: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
    defaultDisplayIndex: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    obligatory: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        default: false
    }
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt',
                'componentContentID', 'objectTypeID',
                'componentTypeID']
        }
    }
}
);

const UserComponent = connectionPool.define('user_component', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    isDisplayed: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
    displayIndex: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'componentID', 'userID', 'ID'] }
    }
});

const ComponentType = connectionPool.define('component_type', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['ID', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'] }
    }
});
const ComponentContent = connectionPool.define('component_content', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Associations:

```
models.Component.belongsTo(models.ComponentContent, { foreignKey: 'componentContentID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.Component.belongsTo(models.ComponentType, { foreignKey: 'componentTypeID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.Component.belongsTo(models.ObjectType, { foreignKey: 'objectTypeID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

models.Component.hasMany(models.UserComponent, { foreignKey: 'componentID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.UserComponent.belongsTo(models.Component, { foreignKey: 'componentID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.User.hasMany(models.UserComponent, { foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

I see no logical reason why query would correctly attach associations if `where` statement is based on `PK` and fail to do so for other field as condition. Documentation does not give any hints. Does anyone know what might be the cause of such behaviour? I'd like to avoid prefinding `user` for `ID` or not requiring the associated models.

Comment: can you show model definitions and associations?

Comment: I updated the question with definitions and associations.

Comment: you missed User model definition

Comment: Ops, sorry, I added it now.

Comment: what does nested: true means? Did not find in the official docs.

Comment: `nested:true` creates a nested structure of associated objects. Without it you don't get an array, but only first object (as far as I remember) - or a first object in the array. They changed documentation a few months ago. For worse.

Comment: If you include hasMany association you'll get an array of associated model objects. Also you can indicate separate: true to make sequelize to query them by a separate query.

Comment: Also you can try subQuery: false on the main level of options (along with 'where'),

Comment: `subQuery: false` worked! Thank you! If you put this as an anwer, I'll gladly accept it! What does it do exactly? I don't see it in the docs either. I guess they changed the `nested:true` in the meantime. I'll remove it, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Ok, wait, I'm not sure if it worked. There's no error anymore, but something has changed and I don't seem to be extracting the relevant data. I need some time to debug this.

Comment: 'subQuery: false' means to do all left or inner joins without nested queries. Just compare two findAll SQL queries with included association belongsTo

Comment: Ok, so that's probably not what I want to do... I do want those subitems. With the `subquery: false` the `ID` search still works correctly, while the `email` search doesn't throw error anymore, but extracts only first (!) of the `UserComponent`s belonging to the `User`. This firt `UserComponent` has all nested models attached (?!) though.

Comment: add separate: true in the include

Comment: Adding `separate:true` to first level of include causes the `Unknown column...` error appear again. In second level it doesn't work as well: error `Only HasMany associations support include.separate`.

Comment: Did you indicate subQuery: false as long as separate: true?

Comment: Yes. `subQuery: false` on the main `where` level and `separate:true` on the `model: models.UserComponent` level. That brings back the `Unknown column...` error.